# Singe or double hyphen?

Tags: hyphens

Is it better to write

foreign-currency-denominated bonds

or

foreign currency-denominated bonds?

Comment: The meaning is different in both, so it depends on what meaning you're after. The first talks about bonds that are denominated in foreign currency, and the second talks about bonds that are currency-denominated and that are also foreign. I suspect the first option is what you're after.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I want to say the first one. On a side note, I think all bonds are currency-denominated so the second example is a bit odd maybe.

Comment: Yes, good point Steven. :-)